# Apache jMeter : Perform load test and delay verification

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I would like to perform a load test on a SOAP webservice.

There are two requests :

1. **createDocument**. *Input*: name, size, date. *Output*: id's document newly created
2. **getDocument**. *Input*: document id. *Output*: id, name, size, date

I would like to perform a load test on the **createDocument** method. Not rocket science, I use the SOAP sampler, very simple.

But in a second step, after the load test (for performance reason) I would to check if the document are really created by calling **getDocument** with the id.

My idea :

- Create a Thread Group for the SOAP sampler
- On the Thread Group, add a postprocessor Beanshell
- in the postprocessor, store the document id in a Java list
- Create an other Thread Group for the verification
- In the Test Plan, check "Run Thread Groups consecutively"
- In the verification Thread find a way to loop the Java list
- For each id, perform a SOAP call

I don't know how to loop over a Java list and call a SOAP sampler for each iteration. Any idea ?

Or generally, do you have a solution more jMeter compliant ?

Thank you

Comment: I did improve the test plan by adding a tearDown thread to perform my verifications but I still think the solution is not state of the art. Any better idea ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the second thread group:

1. Add a Beanshell Sampler which will iterate through the list with document IDs and store them into JMeter Variables, something like:

   ```
   List IDs = bsh.shared.IDs;

   int counter = 1;

   for (String ID : IDs){
       vars.put("ID_" + counter,ID);
       counter++;  
   }
   ```

This will result in variables like:

```
ID_1=somedocumentid
ID_2=someotherdocumentid
....
etc.
```

2. Add a ForEach Controller and configure it as follows:

   - Input Variable Prefix: `ID`
   - Output Variable Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `CURRENT_ID`
   - Make sure that "Add "_" before number" is **checked**

ForEach Controller will iterate through all defined variables with `ID_` prefix and you will be able to refer the current value as `${CURRENT_ID}`

Reference material:

- [Sharing Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) chapter of JMeter's User Manual Best Practices
- [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide
- [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) documentation entry

Comment: Thx for the answer. The way you store the id is interesting.